# Como usar o asp net core 2 no visual studio 2015 community?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core

Instalei o .NET Core 2.0, porém quando vou criar um novo projeto no Visual Studio 2015 não aparece a opção para escolher o asp net core 2.0.

É possível utilizar o mesmo no VS 2015?

Comment: É provável que dê mas não sei como, mas sinceramente é muito mais simples instalar o VS 2017.3 que já vem tudo pronto.

Comment: Pois é, porém o VS2017 pesa muito em meu laptop mesmo com 8Gb de RAM. Tenho um core i5 segunda geração.

Comment: É para pesar menos já que você escolhe o que instalar. O VS só roda em processo de até 4GB então não é para fazer diferença a não ser em casos específicos que poucos usam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Visual Studio 2015 só suporta até o .NET Core 1.1. Oficialmente, o .NET Core 2.0 só está disponível na versão 15.3 ou superior do Visual Studio 2017. Isso se deve ao arquivo de projeto ser diferente (`.csproj` / `.vbproj` vs `project.json`)

Baixe o Visual Studio 2017 [aqui](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/). Na instalação você filtra apenas pelos pacotes que você vai utilizar.

Nunca ouvi falar sobre nenhuma forma extraoficial de usar o .NET Core 2.0 no VS2015.

[Fonte: Annoucing .NET Core 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-core-2-0/)

Comment: Tenho dúvidas se isto é verdade, claro que não vem pronto, mas é pra funcionar sim.